# Get value from promise object in File Reader

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the value returned by a promise however, I am constantly getting a `Promise` object:

```
const readImageToBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => {
        const result = reader.result.toString();
        resolve(result.replace("data:image/jpeg;base64,", ""))
    }
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
});

const imageToBase64 = async (img) => {
   const file = img;
   const result = await readImageToBase64(file).then(response => {
        return response;
   });
   return result;
}
```

And inside another funciton I have:

```
const base64 = images.map(img => {
        return imageToBase64(img)
    })
```

However when I do `console.log(base64)` I get an Array containing promises rather than strings.

Comment: Dose this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459419/1008999

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Promise.all to resolve your array of promises:

```js
const result = await Promise.all(base64);
```